# Почему ExcelWriter не записывает данные в одну и туже страницу?

Tags: python, pandas

Моя программа считывает данные с .xlsx файла, обрабатывает его, далее я записываю данные в дата фреймы. Через ExcelWriter создаю страницы в .xlsx и записываю туда данные из дата фреймов.

Я писал этот код на ПК в офисе и код работал как нужно, но когда я запускаю этот же код с домашнего ПК, мне выдает ошибку:

> Sheet already exists and if_sheet_exists is set to 'error'.

Не понимаю как так, один и тот же код. Использую оболочку PyCharm. Ниже прилагаю отрезок кода. Кто понимает в чём тут дело, подскажите пожалуйста.

Самый главный парадокс проблемы в том, что на другом ПК этот же код работает отлично, возможно проблема в самом PyCharm.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('C:\Myronchuk\Pyton\File for open\HO.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    data1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='2G>LTE', index=False)
    data2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='2G>LTE', startcol=3, startrow=0, index=False)
    data3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LTE>2G', index=0)
    data4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LTE>2G', startcol=3, startrow=0, index=False)
    data5.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LTE>2G', startcol=6, startrow=0, index=False)
    data6.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LTE>LTE', index=False)
    data7.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LTE>LTE', startcol=3, startrow=0, index=False)
    data8.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LTE>LTE', startcol=6, startrow=0, index=False)
    data9.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LTE>3G', index=False)
    data10.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LTE>3G', startcol=3, startrow=0, index=False)
```

Пишу этот вопрос второй раз, в первый мою тему скрестили с похожей темой. Там предложили другой вариант записи данных в .xlsx, я попробовал воспользоваться и им, результат такой же.

> Error: Sheet '2G>LTE' already exists and if_sheet_exists is set to 'error'.

Код второго варианта кода прилагаю:

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook


def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None,
                       truncate_sheet=False,
                       **to_excel_kwargs):
    """
    Append a DataFrame [df] to existing Excel file [filename]
    into [sheet_name] Sheet.
    If [filename] doesn't exist, then this function will create it.

    @param filename: File path or existing ExcelWriter
                     (Example: '/path/to/file.xlsx')
    @param df: DataFrame to save to workbook
    @param sheet_name: Name of sheet which will contain DataFrame.
                       (default: 'Sheet1')
    @param startrow: upper left cell row to dump data frame.
                     Per default (startrow=None) calculate the last row
                     in the existing DF and write to the next row...
    @param truncate_sheet: truncate (remove and recreate) [sheet_name]
                           before writing DataFrame to Excel file
    @param to_excel_kwargs: arguments which will be passed to `DataFrame.to_excel()`
                            [can be a dictionary]
    @return: None

    Usage examples:

    >>> append_df_to_excel('d:/temp/test.xlsx', df)

    >>> append_df_to_excel('d:/temp/test.xlsx', df, header=None, index=False)

    >>> append_df_to_excel('d:/temp/test.xlsx', df, sheet_name='Sheet2',
                           index=False)

    >>> append_df_to_excel('d:/temp/test.xlsx', df, sheet_name='Sheet2',
                           index=False, startrow=25)

    (c) [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741205/maxu?tab=profile)
    """
    # Excel file doesn't exist - saving and exiting
    if not os.path.isfile(filename):
        df.to_excel(
            filename,
            sheet_name=sheet_name,
            startrow=startrow if startrow is not None else 0,
            **to_excel_kwargs)
        return

    # ignore [engine] parameter if it was passed
    if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
        to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl', mode='a')

    # try to open an existing workbook
    writer.book = load_workbook(filename)

    # get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
    # if it was not specified explicitly
    if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
        startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row

    # truncate sheet
    if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
        # index of [sheet_name] sheet
        idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
        # remove [sheet_name]
        writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
        # create an empty sheet [sheet_name] using old index
        writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)

    # copy existing sheets
    writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}

    if startrow is None:
        startrow = 0

    # write out the new sheet
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)

    # save the workbook
    writer.save()


append_df_to_excel('C:\Myronchuk\Pyton\File for open\HO.xlsx', data1, sheet_name='2G>LTE', index=False)
append_df_to_excel('C:\Myronchuk\Pyton\File for open\HO.xlsx', data2, sheet_name='2G>LTE', index=False, startcol=3, startrow=0)
append_df_to_excel('C:\Myronchuk\Pyton\File for open\HO.xlsx', data3, sheet_name='LTE>2G', index=False)
append_df_to_excel('C:\Myronchuk\Pyton\File for open\HO.xlsx', data4, sheet_name='LTE>2G', index=False, startcol=3, startrow=0)
append_df_to_excel('C:\Myronchuk\Pyton\File for open\HO.xlsx', data5, sheet_name='LTE>2G', index=False, startcol=6, startrow=0)
append_df_to_excel('C:\Myronchuk\Pyton\File for open\HO.xlsx', data6, sheet_name='LTE>LTE', index=False)
append_df_to_excel('C:\Myronchuk\Pyton\File for open\HO.xlsx', data7, sheet_name='LTE>LTE', index=False, startcol=3, startrow=0)
append_df_to_excel('C:\Myronchuk\Pyton\File for open\HO.xlsx', data8, sheet_name='LTE>LTE', index=False, startcol=6, startrow=0)
append_df_to_excel('C:\Myronchuk\Pyton\File for open\HO.xlsx', data9, sheet_name='LTE>3G', index=False)
append_df_to_excel('C:\Myronchuk\Pyton\File for open\HO.xlsx', data10, sheet_name='LTE>3G', index=False, startcol=3, startrow=0)
```

K сожалению, версию модулей **openpyxl** и **pandas** на рабочем ПК сейчас указать не могу, но версии на домашнем пк приложу ниже на скринах:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Укажите в вопросе версии модулей `openpyxl` и `pandas` для офисного и для домашнего окружения

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по вашему коду:

```
    ...
    data3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LTE>2G', index=0)
    data4.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LTE>2G', startcol=3, startrow=0, index=False)
    data5.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LTE>2G', startcol=6, startrow=0, index=False)
    ...
```

основная проблема в том, что вы дописываете столбцы по частям хотя можно было бы сначала объединить все, что нужно писать в один фрейм и уже его записывать в Excel:

```
lte_2g = pd.concat([d.reset_index(drop=True) for d in [data3, data4, data5]], axis=1)
lte_2g.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='LTE>2G', index=0)
```

Comment: Эта манипуляция сработала, только столбцы идут по порядку друг за другом (колонка A,B,C,D,E,F). А я бы хотел так - A,B; D,E; G,H ( тоесть пропуск через столбик). И самое главное что меня озадачило - мой код с добавлением дата фреймов поочередно - работает на другом ПК и не выдает никаких ошибок. В любом случае спасибо  большое за вашу подсказку

Comment: @ДимаМирончук, Pandas Core Team в очередной раз "улучшил" работу с Excel файлами - это привело к тому, что старые наработки теперь не работают (это касается и моей функции `append_df_to_excel `) :( PS самым простым решением для вас будет установить дома ту же версию Pandas, которую вы используете на офисном компе

Comment: Да, наверное так и сделаю. Хотя работать не на последней версии чего либо тоже наверное не совсем правильно... )

Comment: @ДимаМирончук, ну, тут уже придется сделать выбор - [ехать или шашечки](http://esperanto-plus.ru/aforism/anekdotoj-pro-taksistoj.htm) ;)